# What's the difference between the 'originalText' and 'word' keys in a token?

Tags: nltk, stanford-nlp

When using `CoreNLPParser` from `NLTK` with [CoreNLP Server](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html), the resulting *tokens* contain both an `'originalText'` key and a `'word'` key.

**What's the difference between the two? Is there any documentation about them?**

I've only found [this issue](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1746), which mentioned the `origintalText` key, but it doesn't answer my questions.

```
from nltk.parse.corenlp import CoreNLPParser 

corenlp_parser = CoreNLPParser('http://localhost:9000', encoding='utf8')
text = u'我家没有电脑。'

result = corenlp_parser.api_call(text, {'annotators': 'tokenize,ssplit'})
print(result)
```

prints

```
{
   "sentences":[
      {
         "index":0,
         "tokens":[
            {
               "index":1,
               "word":"我家",
               "originalText":"我家",
               "characterOffsetBegin":0,
               "characterOffsetEnd":2
            },
            {
               "index":2,
               "word":"没有",
               "originalText":"没有",
               "characterOffsetBegin":2,
               "characterOffsetEnd":4
            },
            {
               "index":3,
               "word":"电脑",
               "originalText":"电脑",
               "characterOffsetBegin":4,
               "characterOffsetEnd":6
            },
            {
               "index":4,
               "word":"。",
               "originalText":"。",
               "characterOffsetBegin":6,
               "characterOffsetEnd":7
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Update:

It seems the [`Token`](https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/simple/Token.html) implements `HasWord` and `HasOriginalText`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `word` is transformed a little bit to make it, e.g., possible to print it in an S-Expression (i.e., a parse tree). So, parentheses and other braces become tokens like `-LRB-` (left round brace). In addition, quotes are normalized to be backticks (``) and forward ticks ('') and some other little things.

`originalText`, by contrast, is the literal original text of the token that can be used to reconstruct the original sentence.